# javascript - variable from HTML class?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with some HTML and JavaScript code. In the html there is a line:

```
<b>Project ID: <span class="project_id"></span></b>
```

Thus `class="project_id"` has a value associated to it and it is written to the page when loaded.

I would like to use JavaScript to capture this value as a variable;

```
var pID = value of class="project_id"
```

Any ideas or is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic JS:

```
var pID = document.getElementsByClassName("project_id")[0].innerHTML;
```

or in jQuery:

```
var pID = $('.project_id').text();
```

You may need to use a more specific selector if there are multiple elements with class `project_id` on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery which makes your app simpler:

```
var pID = $(".project_id").first().text();
```

Make sure that you include "jQuery": `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js" />`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use id instead of class, after that you can do this:

```
var value = document.getElementById('project_id').innerHTML; // native JS
var value = $('#project_id').html(); // or jQuery variant
```

An ID selector is about the fastest method to select elements. It seems as if there is only one point you need this from, hence an unique ID makes more sense than a class.

Comment: it's by class, not ID

Comment: Commented before edit. OK.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of that element, and that element is unique, put ID on it, so make it `<span id="project_id" > </span>`
After that, in JS, just type this:

`var id = document.getElementById('project_id').innerHTML;`

That should do.

Also, you can use  jquery, to simplify your javascript. 
`$("#project_id").text();`  - for id
`$(".project_id").text();`- for class.

but bare in mind that if you have more elements with same class it is not wise to reference it this way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all let's improve your HTML:

```
<strong>Project ID: <span id="project_id"></span></strong>
```

Now you can do in good old javascript:

```
var pID = document.getElementById('project_id').innerHTML;
```

Or use jQuery if available:

```
var pID = $("#project_id").text();
```

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by different ways, I have used javascript querySelector() method to access its  content.. 
See the code here...

```
<html>
<body onload>
<b>Project ID: <span class="project_id">P102</span></b>
<script>
    var pID=document.querySelector('span[class]').innerHTML;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```